# How do I start a new thread to do calculations to prevent memory errors in the GUI for kivy?

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I have a simple prime number checker that ran into memory issues at 16 digits plus when I ran on mobile device. I figured I could fix this by making the prime_number checker run on a separate thread as the GUI. Looking through other examples hasn't helped me, but I seem to have instead added random parts from different examples. Anyway here is the code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.lang import Builder

from numpy import remainder, sqrt, floor

from datetime import datetime
import threading


Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    number: number_input
    check: check_button
    answer: answer
    time: time

    canvas:

        Color:
            rgba: .2, .2, .5, .5
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


        # answer button
        Color:
            rgba: .5, .8, .8, .5
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, root.height / 3
            size: root.width / 2, root.height / 10

        # time button
        Color:
            rgba: .2, .5, .5, .5
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, root.height / 6
            size: root.width, root.height / 10


    TextInput:

        id: number_input
        pos: root.width / 4, 2 * root.height / 3
        size: root.width / 2, root.height / 10
        multiline: False 
        input_filter: 'int'
        hint_text: 'Enter number' 
        write_tab: False


    Button:

        id: check_button
        pos: root.width / 2, root.height / 3
        size: root.width / 2, root.height / 10
        text: 'Check'
        on_press: 
            root.start_second_thread()

    Label:

        id: answer
        text: 'Answer'
        pos: 0, root.height / 3
        size: root.width / 2, root.height / 10

    Label:

        id: time
        pos: 0, root.height / 6
        size: root.width, root.height / 10
        text: 'Time taken'
''')

class MainScreen(Widget):

    number = ObjectProperty(None)
    check = ObjectProperty(None)
    answer = ObjectProperty(None)
    time = ObjectProperty(None)

    def start_second_thread(self):

        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=self.prime_checker)
        thread2.start()
        #thread2.join()
        print(threading.activeCount())

    def prime_checker(self, *args):

        ans = ''
        now = datetime.now()
        if self.number.text == '':
            #self.answer.text = 'No number entered'
            ans = 'No number entered'
            end = datetime.now() - now
            #self.time_checker(end)

        elif len(self.number.text) > 17:
            #self.answer.text = 'Too big for now'
            ans = 'Too big for now'
            end = datetime.now() - now
            #self.time_checker(end)

        else:
            numb = int(self.number.text)
            upper_limit = int(floor(sqrt(numb)))
            tested = False

            if numb < 2:
                #self.answer.text = 'Not Prime'
                ans = 'Not Prime'
                end = datetime.now() - now
                #self.time_checker(end)

            elif numb == 2:
                #self.answer.text = 'Prime'
                ans = 'Prime'
                end = datetime.now() - now
                #self.time_checker(end)

            elif numb % 2 == 0:
                #self.answer.text = 'Not Prime, 2'
                ans = 'Not Prime, 2'
                end = datetime.now() - now
                #self.time_checker(end)

            else:
                for i in range(3, upper_limit, 2):
                    #if numb % i == 0:
                    if remainder(numb, i) == 0:
                        #self.answer.text = 'Not Prime, {}'.format(i)
                        ans = 'Not Prime, {}'.format(i)
                        tested = True
                        end = datetime.now() - now
                        #self.time_checker(end)
                        break

                if tested == False:
                    #self.answer.text = 'Prime'
                    ans = 'Prime'
                    end = datetime.now() - now
                    #self.time_checker(end)

        self.update_main_thread(ans, end)

    def time_checker(self, some_time):

        some_time = 'This took {0} seconds and {1} milliseconds'.format(some_time.seconds, float(some_time.microseconds) / 1000)
        #self.time.text = some_time

    @mainthread
    def update_main_thread(self, ans, tim):
        self.answer.text = ans
        tim = 'This took {0} seconds and {1} milliseconds'.format(tim.seconds, float(tim.microseconds) / 1000)
        self.time.text = tim


class PrimeNumberCheckerApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PrimeNumberCheckerApp().run()
```

I am sure there are a ton of things I can do better, to which suggestions are welcome; however, the most important thing to me is why the line         print(threading.activeCount()) prints 1 instead of 2. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the thread isn't simply finishing before you get to the print statement?

Comment: Well I guess I never put the print statement in the right place. Been trying for a day and after reading your comment and moving print statement couple lines down it's now doing what I wanted. Thanks.

On a side note, I will close question when I figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Natecat, it seems the thread was just finishing before the print statement. If anyone else runs into problem similar I just moved print statement down a couple lines to

```
    def prime_checker(self, *args):

        print(threading.activeCount())
        ...
```

to get what I expected. Thanks Natecat for quick answer.